# Using Entity Framework One To Many insert, inserts Foreign model

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, duplicates

I'm new to Entity Framework, any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm simply trying to Insert a Contract object using EF.

Contract Model:

```
public class Contract
{
    AccStorageEntities db = new AccStorageEntities();
    private ICollection<Room> RoomsList;
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Room> Rooms
    {
        get
        {
            if(RoomsList == null){
                RoomsList= db.Rooms.Where(rm => rm.Contract.ContractId == this.ContractId).ToList();
            }
            return RoomsList;
        }
        set
        {
            RoomsList = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Room Model:

```
public class Room
{
    public string RoomId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public RoomClass RoomClass { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm running:

```
        Contract contract = (Contract)Session["tempContract"];
        db.Contracts.Add(contract);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

When I do this it tries to re-insert all the Room contained within the Contract object, when all I want is to update the Rooms foreign key value.

Any help would be really appreciated.

*: : : : UPDATE : : : :*

Something really strange is happening.

If I try *SaveChanges()* method as a direct result of a submit post it works as expected. But if I save the model in a session and then try to insert that model from another page, it tries to reinsert all the foreign objects.

Comment: I dont know what you're doing with the rooms collection, but ef will load that for you as long as you haven't turned off lazy loading

Comment: that part works as expected. Even if I simple get;set; it doesn't affect the issue I'm having unfortunately.

Comment: Cool. Have you made sure the entities are attached to the context?

Comment: Sorry, new to this. How can I check that?

Would you say technically what I've done should work as expected?

Comment: [See the 'Attaching an existing entity to the context' section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but unfortunately it doesn't explain why Adding to context from HttpPost method the insertion works, but if I pass the responsibility to another function it tries to reinsert all foreign models.